# searching image from the discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js, google-image-search

I am using google-images and image-search-google npm package, but the outcome from the "usage" part of the package is either empty or 'error: can't send an empty message' I'm really confused

I tried exactly from the page, but still the same result, I found a tutorial that alike, but the same outcome now I am really confused

```js
const {RichEmbed, Attachment} = require('discord.js')
const GoogleImage = require('image-search-google')
const {saveGoogle, google_api} = require('../config.json')
const google = new GoogleImage(saveGoogle, google_api);

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
        google.search("John Cena").then(result => {
          if(!result) return console.log('FAILED');
          console.log(result)

          const attachment = new Attachment(result.url);
          message.channel.send(attachment);

        }).catch(e => console.log(e))
};
```

```
(node:12184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: The resource must be a string or Buffer.
    at ClientDataResolver.resolveFile (D:\Workspace\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientDataResolver.js:278:27)
    at Promise.all.options.files.map.file (D:\Workspace\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:173:30)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at TextChannel.send (D:\Workspace\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:40)
    at google.search.then.result (D:\Workspace\DiscordBot\commands\image.js:13:27)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

This is the outcome I get with 'Can't send an empty message' error

Answer (score 0):

There's two main problems I see with your current code:

1. `google.search(...)` should be returning a (promised) array of objects.
2. An image must be sent via an attachment in Discord.js.

To solve these issues, you can use this revised code:

```js
const { Attachment } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  try {
    const [result] = await google.search('John Cena', { page: 1 });

    if (!result) return await message.channel.send(':x: No images found!');

    const attachment = new Attachment(result.url);
    await message.channel.send(attachment);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}; // This semicolon isn't a mistake; you're assigning a value to a property.
```

Here's why it works:

- `[result]` is part of the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax. This line declares `result` as the first element of the array returned by the search. This fixes the problem of `result` being an array of objects.
- `attachment` is a Discord [Attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) which can be sent properly in a message. The first parameter of the constructor is the URL/path to the image. For this, we can use the `url` property of the object from the image search. The second parameter, which I omitted due to its lack of necessity in this case, would be the name of the file to show in Discord.
- The attachment is sent in the message, and the image appears. Voila!

Other resources:

- [Discord.js Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)
- [`image-search-google`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-search-google)

Comment: Still outcome a problem

undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.run (D:\Workspace\DiscordBot\commands\image.js:13:50)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: My mistake! I missed a `return`. Try again?

Comment: It did work, but it gives the outcome of `result` to undefined

Comment: There's most likely something wrong with `image-search-google` or your API credentials if it always returns undefined. Try removing the restructuring assignment and logging `result` then to make sure.

Comment: the `undefined` is the outcome of logging the result

Comment: `result` without the destructuring (not "restructuring," autocorrect) assignment or with it?

Comment: I did the const with destructuring, and print the log of `result` without the destructuring, but I did remove it to test it out but it didn't work either

Comment: Are you sure `image-search-google` is set up properly? Check the documentation of the package.

Comment: I tried like the [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-search-google module/package said and got this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: The resource must be a string or Buffer.`

Comment: You might want to edit your question with the code you're now using and the new error. You're one step closer now that the code is working.